# DB visualizer query running for a long time without producing any output

Tags: hive, dbvisualizer

Hi i connected Hive using DB visualizer and fired a simple join query to fetch two columns according to the filter applied. But the query was running for more than an hour with the status "Executing". I fired the same query in Hive logging through Putty and got the result in less than 20 seconds.

Can anyone help me to understand why the query in DB visualizer was running for a long time without producing any output.

Query used:

```
SELECT
  A.ORDER,
  B.ORDER1
FROM
 ORDER A
 INNER JOIN DUORDER B ON A.ORDER=B.ORDER1 AND A.TYPE ='50'
```

(The result set contain only 400 records)

Answer (score -3):

To analyze why, we need more info. Please please open Tools->Debug Window in DbVisualizer and enable debugging (just for DbVisualizer, not JDBC). Execute the query again, stopping it after some time (say a few minutes). Then submit a support request using Help->Contact Support, and make sure that Attach Logs is enabled. This will give us the info we need to see what may be wrong.

Best Regards,
Hans (DbVisualizer team)

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: It is the only answer that is possible since we need more info to tell what may cause this.

Comment: @Hans submitted the logs to the support team as you suggested.